# How to run Xcode 5.1.1, in OS EL Capitan 10.11.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, osx-yosemite

I have just updated my Mac from Yosemite to Capitan 10.11.1. Before updated Xcode 5.1.1 was work fine (in Yosemite) . But now when I run then it (in  Capitan 10.11.1) shows:

> You can’t use this version of the application “Xcode.app” with this version of OS X.

I also tried this command:

```
/Applications/Xcode5.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

But does not work. I need run it in Capitan.

Comment: So what's wrong with using Xcode 7?

Comment: @ trojanfoe , whenever I create ipa file from archive in Xcode 7. It crashes. Xcode 7 creates only archive successfully but when I create ipa file it crashes. I have follow mostly solution to resolve  it, but does not work.

Comment: @Monusingh How about posting the crash? Did you try Xcode 6.4 ?

Comment: try this command once `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode </dev/null &>/dev/null &`

Comment: @ Fabio, yes same issue.

Comment: if you have multiple copy the command does not work, set the correct xcode app or correct path and check once

Comment: @ Anbu . it opens/runs Xcode 7. I need run Xcode 5.1.1

Comment: @Anbu, let me check out.

Comment: xcode 5 is kind of legacy software now. am not sure if you could submit build to apple with even now.

Comment: @Shubhank , I don't have submit app to app store. I have to share just ipa file to tester and client .

Comment: what about xcode 6 ?

Comment: @Shubhank, Xcode 6 also not working , It crashes + hangs for long time .

Comment: does the ipa crash or the xcode itself ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96375/discussion-between-monu-singh-and-shubhank).

Answer (score 1):

The app is called "Xcode.app", not "Xcode5.app", so use this command instead

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

It is the same code that you posted, but with Xcode.app instead of Xcode5.app

Comment: @ SD1213, When you have more than one Xcode, it saves your Mac like Xcode.app, Xcode2.app and so on. So, I have just gave demo example as Xcode5.app.

Comment: Any luck with this SD1213?

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode </dev/null &>/dev/null &

but, I wasn't able to get the app to work properly even though it managed to open.

Sorry, it was so many months ago that I forgot what happened